# Как сделать такой фон

Tags: css

Как сделать такой фон. Через Фотошоп или CSS. Типа матового стекла

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

через фотошоп.

Comment: понизить контраст добавить какой нибудь lens blur.
...или просто фоток наделать не в фокусе.

Comment: может не по теме, но все же, вдруг пригодится..

Чтобы добиться такого размытия, как Tilt-shift и Bokeh, для фотошопа, помимо обычного размытия, есть плагин Alien Skin Bokeh 2, который размывает очень профессионально. Кроме полного размытия фона можно сделать вот такой "[мультик][1]" ).


  [1]: http://www.forum.sony-club.ru/photo/data/500/DSC03741-1sm.jpg

Comment: спасибо @NoName

Answer (score 3):

А [вот пример](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/spoiler-filter.php) того, как размыть подложку с помощью CSS фильтров.

Answer (score 1):

Все примеры, которые находил в инете, либо с помощью сторонних библиотек, либо работают только в Chrome - кривой ie не хочет обрабатывать filter: blur(n_px) ;(((

Проблему решил следующим образом на чистом html + css:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#id_child {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
}

#id_parent {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#id1_text {
  position: static;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

#svg-image-blur {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.svg-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: url(#blur-effect);
}
```

```html
<div id="id_parent">

  <div id="id_child">
    <div id="id1_text">
      <h2>Welcome to our website!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <svg id="svg-image-blur">  
           <image xlink:href="no-blur.png" preserveAspectRatio="none" class="svg-image" width="100%" height="100%" />
           <filter id="blur-effect"> <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" /> </filter>
       </svg>

</div>
```

Суть тут в том, что svg-блок должен располагаться внутри элемента с **position: absolute;** , иначе некорректно рассчитывается высота вложенного элемента (картинки), если задавать её для родителей (в данном случае, блока **id_parent**) в % (percentage). Высота у **svg-image-blur** получается 150px - дефолтная для svg-элементов. То есть, или ставим родителю **position: absolute;**, или высоту родителя нужно задать жёстко в px (pixels).

Более изящного и краткого решения придумать не удалось.